# Prestashop 1.6 display custom field in Feature Add/Edit form

Tags: php, smarty, e-commerce, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am able to display my custom field in Feature Value Add/Edit form by overriding `AdminFeaturesController` and overriding `initFormFeatureValue()` function.

I want to do the same for Feature Add/Edit form but cannot find function to override. I tried `renderForm()` function but didn't work.

Which file/class/controller/function should I look into to override Feature Add/Edit form to display my custom field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I fixed it. Actually had to call `AdminController::renderForm()` instead of `parent::renderForm()` in my override.

Answer (score 0):

use `$this->fields_form_override` instead of `$this->fields_form` in the override and `return parent::renderForm();`

Comment: You may want to add some helpful details about why to use one method over the other and reference some class documentation if neccessary.